# Make smooth gliding animation SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

So, I have a Sprite that is not allowed to move outside the screen. I made a function that puts the player back into the screen, where it should be (I set the origin of the player right in the middle of it, that's what *0.5 stands for):

```
    if (playerSprite.getPosition().y + playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().height*0.5 > VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height)
        playerSprite.setPosition(Vector2f(playerSprite.getPosition().x, VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height - playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().height*0.5));

    if (playerSprite.getPosition().x + playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().width*0.5 > VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width)
        playerSprite.setPosition(VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width - playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().width*0.5, playerSprite.getPosition().y);

    if (playerSprite.getPosition().y - playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().height*0.5 < 0)
        playerSprite.setPosition(Vector2f(playerSprite.getPosition().x, playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().height*0.5));

    if (playerSprite.getPosition().x - playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().width*0.5 < 0)
        playerSprite.setPosition(Vector2f(playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().width*0.5, playerSprite.getPosition().y));
```

With this pice of code, my player doesn't just stop when it hits the margin of the screen (when it's not perpendicular, of course), but instead, it glides smoothly on the edge of the screen.
But when I tried to do the same thing for a another Sprite, let's say a rectangular Sprite, the player just stops, no matter the angle of collision. Can anyone explain to me this behaviour and maybe advise me on how to make it slide along it's margins?
This would be what I already tried (here is only for up moving, it's analogue for left, right, down):

```
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::W)
sprite.movePlayer('W', speed);
    if(playerSprite.getGlobalBounds().intersects(entity.getGlobalBounds()))
sprite.movePlayer('S', speed);
```

Comment: Does it always stop your movement no matter which side you hit?  Based on your second code snippet I would expect some sides to "slide" and some to "stick".  The problem (or *a* problem) is that the order of your processing matters.  For example, lets say you are moving up-right into the left side of the entity.  If you check vertical movement before horizontal, you will see that there is a collision and reverse the vertical movement *before* checking horizontal movement, which will make you stick.  You need to figure out a way to decouple the collision checking from the resulting correction.

Comment: Yes, it stops my movement, doesn't matter which side I hit. And I see your point, but I'm not sure this will solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be that for every update frame you are performing a hard negation of the sprite's velocity in the direction of the boundary it has hit, while still applying velocity in the direction for which it is still within bounds.  When the sprite hits the bounds, freeze all movement, not just movement toward the boundary.